# Does SELECT remove dead rows like VACUUM does?

Tags: postgresql, select, vacuum, postgresql-11

I was fiddling with `VACUUM` and noticed some unexpected behavior where `SELECT`ing rows from a table seems to reduce the work `VACUUM` has to do afterwards.

### Test Data

**Note: autovacuum is disabled**

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (num bigint);
ALTER TABLE numbers SET (
  autovacuum_enabled = 'f',
  toast.autovacuum_enabled = 'f'
);

INSERT INTO numbers SELECT generate_series(1, 5000);
```

### Trial 1

Now we run an update on all the rows,

```
UPDATE numbers SET num = 0;
```

And when we run `VACUUM (VERBOSE) numbers;` we get,

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.numbers"
INFO:  "numbers": removed 5000 row versions in 23 pages
INFO:  "numbers": found 5000 removable, 5000 nonremovable row versions in 45 out of 45 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 6585
There were 0 unused item pointers.
```

### Trial 2

Now we issue another `UPDATE`, but this time we add a `SELECT` afterward,

```
UPDATE numbers SET num = 1;
SELECT * FROM numbers;
```

And when we run `VACUUM (VERBOSE) numbers;` we get,

```
INFO:  vacuuming "public.numbers"
INFO:  "numbers": removed 56 row versions in 22 pages
INFO:  "numbers": found 56 removable, 5000 nonremovable row versions in 45 out of 45 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 6586
There were 56 unused item pointers.
```

What exactly is happening here? Why does the second version I run, after the `SELECT` remove dead tuples from the pages it visits, quite like `VACUUM` does?

I am running Postgres 11.3 on macOS 10.14.5.

Comment: What client do you use to run your commands? Is autocommit enabled in it?

Comment: I'm going to delete the question *"Is VACUUM table basically just SELECT * FROM table under the hood?"* (it's not) I think that's a good follow up, the answer here is simply that SELECT can remove dead rows, and it does share that in common with VACUUM. How they're different will be a very exhaustive conversation about XID rollover, and a ton of other things. That question is basically "What other things does vacuum do besides remove dead rows." (Which would be kind of vague)

Comment: @mustaccio I did these tests with a Ruby script using ActiveRecord, which uses the PG gem under the hood. I believe autocommit is enabled by default as you don't need to issue any COMMIT unless BEGIN is used explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this post on /r/PostgreSQL](https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/bx7fhd/does_select_remove_dead_rows_like_vacuum_does/eq48lhw/) to an [answer by Laurenz Albe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51167809/124486) it seems that Heap Only Tuples (HOT) updates may be responsible. From the description of [HOT updates in `src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/access/heap/README.HOT;hb=HEAD)

> Effectively, space reclamation happens during tuple retrieval when the
>   page is nearly full (<10% free) and a buffer cleanup lock can be
>   acquired.  This means that `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, and `SELECT` can trigger space
>   reclamation, but often not during `INSERT ... VALUES` because it does
>   not retrieve a row.

The quote is not in the original answer, but the rest is a quote,

> To support or refute this theory, run the following query:
>
> ```
> SELECT n_tup_upd, n_tup_hot_upd
> FROM pg_stat_user_tables
> WHERE schemaname = 'public' AND relname = 'TABLE_NAME';
> ```
>
> If `n_tup_hot_upd` is greater than zero, we have got a case.

Comment: Now we're talking. +1

Comment: HOT seems to be a good explanation. If I `CREATE INDEX idx_numbers ON numbers USING btree (num)`, VACUUM output changes to `INFO:  "numbers": removed 5000 row versions in 45 pages`. Note however that in the index-less scenario, `n_tup_hot_upd` is always 0, both between the UPDATE and SELECT and between the SELECT and VACUUM. I also made sure to run `SELECT pg_sleep(10)` between each statement so that statistics are up-to-date (I do see `seq_scan: 2`, one for the UPDATE and one for the SELECT).

Comment: Does the select generate WAL in this case? I was under the impression that selects don’t generate WAL at all. If yes, this would mean the removal of dead rows gets propagated to any slaves. If no, this means that vacuuming is still necessary on the slave. It would also mean that masters and slaves aren’t bit identical. Hmm, maybe I need to do some research and post a question and/or answer or two.

Answer (score 1):

In the special case of an unindexed table, yes, SELECT can do the same work as VACUUM (as far as removing dead rows is concerned).

Comment: Could you add an explanation?